# Use try/catch block on called functions or task.wait()?

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

what's the difference between using try catch surrounding a function block that is called by some task and calling try/catch on task.wait(). If i take care of exceptions within the function, do i still need to worry about any exception that might occur from task.wait() ?

```
var factory = new TaskFactory();
task t1= factory.StartNew(() => funA();
t1.Wait();


void funcA()
{
  try{..}
  .
  .
  catch{..}
}
```

Or

```
var factory = new TaskFactory();
task t1= factory.StartNew(() => funA();
try
{
  t1.Wait();
}
catch{....}

void funcA()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first block you provided you wouldn't be able to catch any of these exceptions that may occur:

> - `ObjectDisposedException`: The Task has been disposed.
> - `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: timeout is a negative number other than -1 milliseconds, which represents an infinite time-out -or- timeout is greater than MaxValue.
> - `AggregateException`: The Task was canceled -or- an exception was thrown during the execution of the Task.

From [`Task.Wait()` documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx)

Comment: :O , it's was there all along, MSDN is so annoying to browse.thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

I use to handle exceptions in tasks with continuations, easier IMO:

```
Task myTask= Task.Factory.StartNew( ... ).ContinueWith(myTaskFinished=> 
{
   if (myTaskFinished.IsCompleted)
   {
       // Hooray
   }

   if (myTaskFinished.IsFaulted)
   {
       foreach (Exception ex in myTaskFinished.Exception.InnerExceptions)
           //Exception handle..
   }

   if(myTaskFinished.IsCanceled)
   { 
        //Cancellation token?
   }
});

myTask.Wait();
```